# Can't remove vstack element from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ros

My list is formed of vstack elements :

```
     X = vstack([x,y,time])
```

I am using this code to remove points from the list

```
    # Remove old points from the list
    point_tempo = []
    for i in range(0,len(self.points)):
        if self.points[i][0,0] <-0.5:
           point_tempo.append(self.points[i])
    for j in range(0,len(point_tempo)):
        self.points.remove(point_tempo[j])
```

And I am getting this error:

> File
>   "/home/group5/Documents/catkin_ws/src/platoon_pkgv2/nodes/bubble_odom.py",
>   line 121, in sync_odo_cb
>       self.points.remove(point_tempo[j]) ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or
>   a.all()

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [code of `remove`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b75160d24b7b/Objects/listobject.c#l2193), in order to find which element to remove, goes through the list and compare each element with the one to remove, using the `==` operator. The problem is that this operator, on a `vstack`, doesn't just return a Boolean but a `vstack` of pairwise Booleans. That's your error.

What you'd better do is record the indices and remove them elements by index:

```
# Remove old points from the list
point_tempo = []
for i, point in enumerate(self.points)): # enumerate is your friend
    if point[0,0] < -0.5:
       point_tempo.append(i)
for i in reversed(point_tempo): # reverse order so that indices remain valid
    self.points.pop(i)
```